# Second derivative of implicit function - answer not matching

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, implicit-differentiation

I have an implicit function $y(x)$ defined with the equation.

$\sin{(x+y)} - y = 0$

I have to find the first and second derivatives of $y$ w.r.t. $x$.

When I am solving it myself I am getting

$$y' = \frac{\cos{(x+y)}} {(1 - \cos{(x+y)})}$$

$$y'' = \frac{-\sin{(x+y)}} {(1 - \cos{(x+y)})^3}$$

But the answer I have (in the book) for $y''$ does not have the minus sign before $\sin(x+y)$.

1. Which one is correct?
2. How do I calculate these $y'$ and $y''$ with Wolfram Alpha, is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Minus sign should be there. The book is wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm OK, thanks. And also, is there a way to compute/verify this with Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @peter.petrov [Check this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=implicit+differentiation&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22implicit+differentiation%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22ImplicitDerivative%22%2C+%22derivativefunction%22%7D+-%3E%22sin%28x%2By%29+-+y+%3D+0%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22ImplicitDerivative%22%2C+%22derivativevariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22)

Comment: @19aksh I saw this already but I don't see how to compute the second derivative there.

Comment: I'm not sure about higher order implicit derivatives in WA, but [symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/implicit-derivative-calculator/implicit%20derivative%20%5Cfrac%7Bd%5E%7B2%7Dy%7D%7Bdx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%2C%20%5Csin%5Cleft(x%2By%5Cright)-y%3D0?or=input) provides an option. Also I think in your book, they should've mentioned the denominator as $(\cos(x+y) - 1)^3$, so the - sign should've got cancelled

Comment: The derivatives of order $1,2\ldots,n$ in  terms of $x$ and $y$ can be calculated by consecutive differentiation of the equation $\sin(x+y)-y=0$. In this way we obtain $n$ identities, with no fractions. The $k$th identity involves the first $k$ derivatives of $y.$ We determine $y'$ from the first equation. Plug in the result to the second identity and determine $y''.$ Plug in $y',y''$ to  the third equation etc. After $n$ steps we get the formula for the $n$th derivative of $y.$